# How to increase the number of lines in output terminal in vs code(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to display a relatively big dataframe (800 rows) with pandas on vscode but i can only get it to 100 rows at most. the output just get cut at line 99 as seen here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4vT1.jpg)

i have tried multiple ways such as pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) and integrated scrollback settings but to no avail. setting the option to display max rows did increase the numbers of rows shown from 10 to 100 but thats about it. I'm not sure if that's a setting in vs code that is limiting the output? the integrated scrollback settings did not do anything

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need change the pandas option setting to display 
the maximum rows **BEFORE** printing the dataframe.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

I created a test dataframe using this method, and the **terminal** showed **all 800 rows**. 
I copy-and-pasted my terminal output into this response.

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)

fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'orange', 'plum', 'nectarine']
animal = ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'cow', 'sheep', 'goat' ,'tiger', 'lion', 'elephant']
colour = ['red', 'orange','yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']

df = pd.DataFrame()                                                                                                                                                                     
N = 800                                                                                                                                                                               
df["Fruit"] = np.random.choice(fruit, size=N)                                                                                                                                     
df["Animal"] = np.random.choice(animal, size=N)                                                                                                                                               
df["Colour"] = np.random.choice(colour, size=N) 

print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
         Fruit    Animal  Colour
0       banana       cow  yellow
1    nectarine      goat     red
2       cherry       cow  yellow
3         kiwi     sheep  orange
4         kiwi      goat   green
5    nectarine     sheep  yellow
6       banana    monkey   green
7         kiwi      lion  violet
8        apple      goat     red
9       orange    monkey  violet
10        plum       cat    blue
11      cherry       dog     red
12      cherry     tiger    blue
13   nectarine     tiger  violet
14      banana  elephant  violet
15       apple      lion  violet
16        plum     sheep     red
17       apple     tiger    blue
18       apple       dog   green
19        plum      lion  yellow
20      banana    monkey  orange
21      orange     sheep   green
22      orange       cow  orange
23   nectarine  elephant  yellow
24      orange     sheep   green
25       apple    monkey  yellow
26      cherry      lion  indigo
27      banana       cat  violet
28       apple     tiger    blue
29      banana      lion  indigo
30      banana       cow  orange
31      banana     tiger     red
32      orange      goat    blue
33      orange    monkey  orange
34      cherry     sheep   green
35      banana       dog  orange
36      banana      lion    blue
37       apple     tiger  orange
38        plum    monkey   green
39      banana       cat  violet
40       apple       cat     red
41        kiwi  elephant  orange
42      banana  elephant  indigo
43      banana     tiger  violet
44       apple       cow  yellow
45       apple      lion  indigo
46       apple       cow  yellow
47      banana  elephant     red
48        plum    monkey  orange
49      cherry       cat  orange
50       apple       cat   green
51        kiwi    monkey  orange
52   nectarine     tiger  indigo
53      banana       dog  violet
54   nectarine  elephant  violet
55      orange  elephant     red
56      cherry       dog  yellow
57      banana      goat    blue
58      banana      goat   green
59        plum      goat  orange
60   nectarine       cow    blue
61   nectarine    monkey  yellow
62      orange     tiger     red
63      cherry    monkey  indigo
64      cherry      goat  orange
65      orange       cow  violet
66   nectarine       dog  violet
67       apple      lion    blue
68      orange      goat  yellow
69      banana       cow     red
70        kiwi       cow  yellow
71       apple      lion  orange
72   nectarine       cat   green
73      orange       dog  violet
74       apple  elephant     red
75      cherry  elephant  violet
76   nectarine     tiger   green
77        kiwi     tiger  violet
78        plum  elephant   green
79      banana    monkey    blue
80   nectarine       dog  indigo
81      banana      lion    blue
82        kiwi      goat  orange
83      banana      goat  violet
84        kiwi       cow  indigo
85      cherry      lion   green
86      orange     tiger  orange
87   nectarine  elephant  violet
88      orange       cow  indigo
89      cherry      lion   green
90        kiwi     sheep     red
91      banana       cow     red
92       apple     tiger   green
93      orange       cow  yellow
94        kiwi    monkey  indigo
95        kiwi       cat  yellow
96        kiwi    monkey  violet
97   nectarine       cow  indigo
98        plum       cow  violet
99        kiwi       cat  indigo
100     banana      goat  orange
101     banana     sheep  yellow
102       kiwi       dog     red
103  nectarine    monkey    blue
104       plum       cow   green
105     cherry      lion  indigo
106       kiwi  elephant  violet
107      apple       cow   green
108     cherry       cat  violet
109      apple       cat   green
110     banana       cow  violet
111       kiwi     sheep    blue
112     cherry       cow  indigo
113      apple      lion  yellow
114       plum       dog  yellow
115       kiwi      lion  indigo
116       kiwi       dog  violet
117       kiwi       cow    blue
118       plum      goat  indigo
119      apple  elephant   green
120     orange  elephant    blue
121      apple     sheep  yellow
122  nectarine      lion    blue
123       plum      lion  yellow
124     cherry     tiger  violet
125  nectarine      goat    blue
126  nectarine     tiger  violet
127       plum     tiger  indigo
128       plum    monkey   green
129       kiwi      lion  indigo
130  nectarine  elephant  yellow
131     orange      lion  yellow
132     orange       dog  orange
133     banana       cow     red
134     banana    monkey     red
135     cherry       cow  orange
136     banana       cow  orange
137     cherry     tiger  indigo
138     orange       dog  violet
139      apple      goat  yellow
140     banana       cat     red
141  nectarine    monkey    blue
142     banana       dog    blue
143     cherry      goat  yellow
144     cherry  elephant  violet
145       kiwi      lion  orange
146  nectarine       cow  violet
147       kiwi     tiger   green
148     banana    monkey    blue
149       kiwi       dog  orange
150      apple      lion   green
151     banana    monkey    blue
152      apple      goat  indigo
153       plum     sheep  yellow
154     cherry    monkey  orange
155  nectarine       dog    blue
156  nectarine  elephant   green
157     orange  elephant  violet
158     orange     tiger  yellow
159       plum       cat   green
160       plum       cow  violet
161       plum       cow   green
162     banana      goat     red
163  nectarine     tiger   green
164       plum       cow     red
165      apple  elephant  indigo
166     cherry       cat  indigo
167      apple    monkey  orange
168     orange       cow  violet
169  nectarine      goat    blue
170  nectarine       dog  yellow
171     orange       cow   green
172     orange       cat     red
173     banana       cow  yellow
174     cherry     tiger  yellow
175       kiwi    monkey  orange
176      apple       cow   green
177     orange  elephant   green
178     orange    monkey   green
179       kiwi       dog  indigo
180       plum       dog    blue
181     cherry       cat  violet
182     banana      lion  violet
183     banana      lion  violet
184  nectarine       cow     red
185  nectarine       dog  orange
186     banana       cow  indigo
187       kiwi       cat  indigo
188     orange    monkey   green
189     cherry     sheep  violet
190     banana  elephant   green
191  nectarine    monkey  yellow
192     cherry       cow  yellow
193  nectarine       cat  orange
194  nectarine    monkey  yellow
195     banana  elephant  indigo
196      apple  elephant  yellow
197      apple       cat     red
198       kiwi       dog  orange
199     orange       dog  yellow
200     banana     sheep     red
201       kiwi    monkey  yellow
202     orange     tiger  yellow
203     orange    monkey   green
204     orange     tiger   green
205       plum     sheep   green
206     orange       cat  violet
207      apple       cow  violet
208       kiwi  elephant  indigo
209     orange      goat  orange
210      apple       dog     red
211      apple      lion  yellow
212       plum     sheep  yellow
213     orange       dog  violet
214       kiwi     tiger     red
215     cherry       cat   green
216       plum     sheep   green
217     orange     sheep  yellow
218     orange       cow  indigo
219     cherry       dog  yellow
220       plum      goat    blue
221     banana    monkey  yellow
222       kiwi       cow   green
223  nectarine       cat     red
224       kiwi      goat     red
225     orange    monkey  indigo
226     banana      goat    blue
227       plum     sheep  violet
228       kiwi      goat  orange
229      apple       cow    blue
230      apple    monkey  indigo
231     orange  elephant    blue
232  nectarine       dog    blue
233       kiwi     sheep    blue
234     orange    monkey    blue
235     orange       cow   green
236      apple     sheep    blue
237     cherry    monkey    blue
238  nectarine  elephant  yellow
239      apple      lion  orange
240     banana  elephant     red
241     cherry       dog  yellow
242     orange    monkey  violet
243     banana      goat   green
244     orange       dog  indigo
245     cherry     sheep     red
246       plum      goat  violet
247       kiwi       dog  orange
248       kiwi       cat  orange
249     cherry      goat  orange
250       kiwi       cow   green
251      apple    monkey     red
252       plum       cat  violet
253  nectarine       cow    blue
254     orange       cow  violet
255     cherry  elephant     red
256      apple       dog     red
257       kiwi     tiger   green
258       plum       cow  violet
259       plum    monkey  indigo
260      apple       dog     red
261  nectarine    monkey    blue
262  nectarine      goat  orange
263      apple       cat     red
264       plum       dog  violet
265     orange    monkey    blue
266  nectarine      lion    blue
267       kiwi      goat  yellow
268  nectarine     tiger  yellow
269       plum      lion    blue
270  nectarine     sheep  indigo
271     orange       dog  violet
272      apple       cat  yellow
273      apple    monkey  indigo
274  nectarine    monkey   green
275       kiwi     tiger     red
276     banana  elephant   green
277  nectarine     tiger   green
278     orange       cat  yellow
279  nectarine       cat     red
280       kiwi      goat  orange
281     banana    monkey  violet
282     orange  elephant   green
283       plum      lion  violet
284     orange      goat  orange
285     cherry      goat  yellow
286     banana       cat  yellow
287     banana       cat    blue
288       kiwi       cow    blue
289     orange       dog   green
290      apple      goat  orange
291     orange     tiger     red
292     cherry     sheep  yellow
293       kiwi    monkey  yellow
294      apple     sheep  orange
295     orange       cow     red
296     banana      goat    blue
297       kiwi       dog     red
298     orange       cow  indigo
299       plum      lion    blue
300       kiwi     tiger    blue
301  nectarine     sheep    blue
302     banana  elephant     red
303       plum      goat     red
304     orange  elephant     red
305       plum      lion  violet
306      apple      lion  violet
307       plum    monkey  yellow
308  nectarine       cow  yellow
309      apple       cat  violet
310       plum     tiger    blue
311       plum      goat     red
312       kiwi    monkey    blue
313       plum       cat  orange
314     orange       dog    blue
315       kiwi     sheep  yellow
316       kiwi      lion   green
317     banana       dog   green
318     banana  elephant    blue
319  nectarine      lion  violet
320      apple    monkey  orange
321       plum      goat  yellow
322  nectarine      goat     red
323     cherry       dog     red
324     banana      goat     red
325      apple     sheep  indigo
326       plum       cow  indigo
327     banana       cat    blue
328       plum    monkey     red
329     banana      goat  violet
330     orange     tiger  indigo
331     orange       cow  indigo
332       plum       cow  orange
333     orange       dog    blue
334       kiwi     tiger    blue
335       plum      lion  violet
336      apple    monkey     red
337  nectarine  elephant     red
338  nectarine       cat    blue
339      apple       cow  violet
340       kiwi       cat    blue
341  nectarine     tiger  violet
342      apple       cow    blue
343  nectarine       cow  violet
344       kiwi      lion  orange
345     cherry     sheep   green
346      apple    monkey  indigo
347     cherry       cat    blue
348      apple     tiger   green
349       plum      lion   green
350       kiwi     sheep  violet
351       plum       dog   green
352     banana       cow   green
353       plum      goat    blue
354     banana       dog  indigo
355       plum      goat   green
356  nectarine      lion  orange
357     orange       cat   green
358       plum    monkey  indigo
359     orange       dog  indigo
360     orange       dog  yellow
361     orange       cat  violet
362       kiwi     tiger    blue
363     banana       cat  orange
364     orange       cow     red
365     cherry      lion   green
366     cherry    monkey  indigo
367       kiwi    monkey  orange
368     cherry    monkey  indigo
369     cherry      goat     red
370      apple    monkey  violet
371  nectarine     sheep  orange
372     banana     sheep   green
373     cherry      lion   green
374      apple       dog  yellow
375     orange  elephant    blue
376       kiwi       cow    blue
377       plum      goat  violet
378     cherry     sheep   green
379  nectarine  elephant  indigo
380       plum     sheep  orange
381     banana      goat  yellow
382       plum      lion  orange
383       plum      lion   green
384     orange       dog  violet
385  nectarine    monkey  yellow
386  nectarine       dog  indigo
387  nectarine    monkey  orange
388     cherry      lion    blue
389     banana     sheep  indigo
390       plum     tiger  yellow
391      apple       cow  indigo
392       plum      goat  violet
393       plum     sheep   green
394     orange       cow  yellow
395  nectarine     tiger     red
396       plum       cow  orange
397       plum     sheep  yellow
398       plum     sheep  violet
399  nectarine      lion     red
400     banana       dog    blue
401     cherry     sheep  indigo
402      apple    monkey     red
403      apple     sheep     red
404     banana       dog   green
405       plum    monkey    blue
406  nectarine    monkey    blue
407     cherry       dog   green
408  nectarine      goat     red
409     orange       cow  orange
410       plum    monkey  indigo
411  nectarine    monkey  violet
412       plum      lion  indigo
413     cherry      goat  yellow
414       kiwi  elephant   green
415     cherry  elephant  yellow
416  nectarine       dog    blue
417     cherry      goat  orange
418     cherry     tiger  yellow
419       kiwi       cat     red
420  nectarine       cat  orange
421     banana    monkey  yellow
422     orange    monkey   green
423       plum    monkey  indigo
424     cherry      lion     red
425     banana       cat  orange
426       plum      goat  orange
427     banana       dog   green
428     cherry       cow  orange
429      apple       cow  violet
430       plum      goat     red
431       kiwi       cow  orange
432     cherry     sheep  orange
433      apple       cow  orange
434     orange     tiger  orange
435       plum      lion  yellow
436     orange       dog    blue
437      apple       cat   green
438     orange    monkey   green
439       plum  elephant    blue
440     cherry     tiger   green
441     orange      lion     red
442       plum       cow  orange
443     banana     tiger  yellow
444     banana       dog    blue
445       plum       cat  indigo
446     cherry     sheep     red
447       plum      lion  orange
448     orange       dog     red
449     orange  elephant  indigo
450  nectarine       cat  violet
451  nectarine      lion  indigo
452     banana    monkey  yellow
453      apple      lion  indigo
454     orange     tiger   green
455       kiwi  elephant    blue
456  nectarine  elephant  indigo
457      apple       cat   green
458  nectarine      lion    blue
459       plum      goat     red
460       kiwi       cat   green
461     orange       cat   green
462      apple       cat    blue
463     orange      goat   green
464     orange       cow  violet
465     orange       cow     red
466  nectarine    monkey  yellow
467     orange       cow  orange
468       kiwi     sheep  violet
469  nectarine       cow  orange
470  nectarine      goat     red
471  nectarine       dog     red
472      apple  elephant  yellow
473     orange       cat  violet
474       kiwi       cat    blue
475     banana       cow  yellow
476       kiwi  elephant  yellow
477       kiwi      lion   green
478      apple       cat     red
479     orange       dog   green
480     orange  elephant  violet
481  nectarine  elephant  violet
482       kiwi     sheep   green
483     banana      lion  indigo
484      apple     sheep     red
485  nectarine      goat    blue
486     banana       cat  violet
487     cherry     tiger  violet
488       plum       cat    blue
489     banana      goat     red
490       plum     sheep  yellow
491     orange       dog  orange
492  nectarine      lion    blue
493     banana  elephant  violet
494      apple     sheep  yellow
495     orange       cow    blue
496  nectarine  elephant   green
497  nectarine      lion  indigo
498     banana       dog  yellow
499  nectarine     tiger  orange
500       kiwi       cow   green
501     cherry       cow  orange
502     orange  elephant  yellow
503     cherry       cow  yellow
504     banana     sheep  violet
505       plum    monkey  violet
506       plum      goat   green
507     orange       cow     red
508      apple     sheep  violet
509     orange    monkey  indigo
510      apple       dog   green
511       kiwi     tiger    blue
512      apple     tiger   green
513       kiwi  elephant  indigo
514     orange     sheep    blue
515     cherry    monkey    blue
516      apple       dog     red
517     cherry  elephant  yellow
518      apple     sheep   green
519      apple       cat  yellow
520     cherry  elephant    blue
521  nectarine     sheep  yellow
522      apple  elephant  yellow
523     cherry     tiger  violet
524      apple  elephant  indigo
525     orange     sheep   green
526       kiwi       cow   green
527       plum      lion   green
528       kiwi     tiger    blue
529       plum     tiger  yellow
530     orange       cat  yellow
531       plum      lion  yellow
532  nectarine       cow    blue
533     cherry      lion   green
534      apple  elephant  indigo
535     banana    monkey    blue
536     banana       dog  violet
537       kiwi       cat    blue
538  nectarine    monkey   green
539       kiwi       cow  orange
540     banana    monkey  orange
541  nectarine       cow  yellow
542     banana       dog    blue
543       plum    monkey  indigo
544     banana     sheep  yellow
545       plum     sheep  yellow
546      apple       cat  indigo
547       plum    monkey    blue
548      apple       cat  orange
549      apple      goat  violet
550     orange      lion  indigo
551  nectarine  elephant  orange
552       plum     sheep   green
553     orange     sheep     red
554       plum  elephant    blue
555  nectarine       dog  orange
556     cherry      lion  yellow
557       kiwi     sheep     red
558       kiwi      lion  orange
559     cherry    monkey  indigo
560     cherry     sheep    blue
561     orange       dog  indigo
562     orange     tiger  orange
563       plum      goat  orange
564       plum     tiger    blue
565  nectarine    monkey    blue
566       kiwi       dog  indigo
567       kiwi    monkey  violet
568      apple     sheep     red
569     orange       cow    blue
570       kiwi       cow  violet
571       plum  elephant     red
572     cherry       dog     red
573  nectarine       cat  indigo
574       plum      lion  indigo
575     banana      goat    blue
576     banana       cow  yellow
577      apple      goat  violet
578      apple       cat     red
579       kiwi      lion  indigo
580      apple       cat    blue
581     cherry       cat    blue
582     orange     sheep  yellow
583     banana       cow   green
584      apple    monkey  orange
585       plum     sheep   green
586      apple     tiger    blue
587     cherry       cow   green
588  nectarine      lion   green
589     banana      goat  violet
590     banana       cow     red
591      apple    monkey    blue
592       kiwi       cat  orange
593       plum     tiger  indigo
594     cherry     tiger  indigo
595  nectarine     sheep  indigo
596     banana       cat  yellow
597     orange    monkey    blue
598     banana      goat  yellow
599       plum       cat     red
600       plum       cat  indigo
601       kiwi       cat   green
602     banana     sheep  orange
603       kiwi      lion  yellow
604      apple     sheep  yellow
605  nectarine       cat   green
606     cherry       dog    blue
607  nectarine     tiger  yellow
608       kiwi       cat  yellow
609       plum     tiger  orange
610       plum     tiger     red
611     cherry       cow  indigo
612     orange    monkey    blue
613       plum       cow  yellow
614     banana       cow   green
615       kiwi      goat    blue
616       plum     tiger  indigo
617     banana       dog    blue
618     banana      goat  violet
619     orange  elephant  indigo
620  nectarine     tiger  violet
621      apple      goat  violet
622      apple       cat     red
623  nectarine     tiger  violet
624  nectarine    monkey    blue
625       plum       cow  orange
626       plum       dog   green
627  nectarine     tiger  orange
628     banana    monkey  yellow
629     banana       cow  indigo
630     banana  elephant  violet
631       plum    monkey  orange
632     orange       dog  yellow
633  nectarine    monkey     red
634     orange    monkey  orange
635       plum     tiger    blue
636     cherry    monkey   green
637       kiwi       cow  orange
638      apple      goat  yellow
639       plum       cat   green
640     banana      goat     red
641     banana       cow    blue
642       plum     sheep  indigo
643     cherry    monkey  violet
644     banana     sheep   green
645       plum    monkey   green
646     cherry       dog  violet
647  nectarine  elephant  yellow
648       kiwi    monkey  yellow
649     banana     sheep  indigo
650  nectarine  elephant     red
651     orange      goat   green
652       plum       cow  orange
653     orange    monkey    blue
654       plum       dog  orange
655     banana  elephant  orange
656     orange       cow  violet
657     orange      goat  orange
658     cherry  elephant  orange
659     banana  elephant  orange
660  nectarine     tiger  yellow
661  nectarine     tiger  orange
662     orange      goat   green
663  nectarine      goat  yellow
664     banana      goat     red
665     banana       cat     red
666      apple     sheep     red
667  nectarine     tiger    blue
668     cherry     sheep  orange
669     banana       cow  violet
670     orange       cow  yellow
671      apple    monkey  violet
672  nectarine    monkey    blue
673  nectarine     sheep  indigo
674       kiwi      goat   green
675  nectarine       dog    blue
676       kiwi     tiger  orange
677     banana      goat     red
678     banana  elephant    blue
679  nectarine       cow    blue
680  nectarine       cat  violet
681  nectarine      lion   green
682     cherry     sheep    blue
683       plum     tiger  orange
684     banana      goat   green
685  nectarine      lion     red
686     banana    monkey  orange
687     orange    monkey  violet
688     orange  elephant  violet
689  nectarine       cow  yellow
690     banana      lion    blue
691     banana  elephant     red
692     orange     tiger   green
693       plum  elephant  yellow
694     orange     tiger  yellow
695     cherry     tiger  violet
696       kiwi       dog  indigo
697     banana       cat  violet
698      apple       cow   green
699     banana      lion   green
700       plum       dog  orange
701     orange       cow     red
702     cherry     sheep    blue
703     orange  elephant   green
704      apple       cat  orange
705  nectarine     tiger  yellow
706  nectarine      lion     red
707  nectarine    monkey  violet
708      apple     tiger  yellow
709     banana       cow    blue
710  nectarine  elephant  orange
711     cherry     tiger  indigo
712       plum      goat    blue
713     banana      lion  indigo
714     cherry       cow  yellow
715       plum       dog  orange
716      apple       cat     red
717  nectarine  elephant  indigo
718      apple      lion  violet
719       kiwi  elephant    blue
720       plum     tiger  orange
721       plum       cat  yellow
722      apple    monkey  yellow
723  nectarine     tiger     red
724      apple       dog  yellow
725     orange      lion  indigo
726      apple      lion  violet
727      apple      lion  orange
728     cherry  elephant     red
729     cherry       cow     red
730     cherry       cow    blue
731     banana  elephant   green
732     orange  elephant  indigo
733     orange       cat  orange
734     banana      lion   green
735     orange     tiger  yellow
736       plum       cow    blue
737     banana     sheep    blue
738     orange  elephant  violet
739       plum       cat     red
740       plum       dog     red
741       kiwi     sheep  violet
742       plum      lion   green
743      apple    monkey   green
744     cherry      goat   green
745      apple     sheep     red
746       plum  elephant  indigo
747     orange      lion    blue
748       kiwi      goat  orange
749       plum       cow  violet
750      apple       cat   green
751     cherry     tiger  orange
752       kiwi       cow    blue
753       plum      goat  orange
754       kiwi       cow  orange
755  nectarine       cat  indigo
756       plum       cow   green
757  nectarine  elephant  yellow
758       plum       cat  orange
759       plum      lion     red
760       plum     sheep   green
761  nectarine       cat  yellow
762       plum       cow    blue
763       kiwi       cat  violet
764       kiwi       cow  violet
765     cherry     sheep  orange
766       kiwi      goat     red
767     banana       cat  violet
768       kiwi     sheep     red
769       kiwi      lion  yellow
770     banana       cat  indigo
771  nectarine       cow     red
772  nectarine     sheep  orange
773       plum    monkey    blue
774       kiwi      lion  yellow
775     banana    monkey  indigo
776     cherry       cow     red
777       plum  elephant    blue
778     banana      goat   green
779       plum  elephant  indigo
780       plum       cat   green
781     orange      goat    blue
782       plum     sheep  indigo
783  nectarine      goat   green
784      apple     sheep  indigo
785     cherry    monkey  violet
786       plum      goat   green
787       plum      lion   green
788     banana     tiger  violet
789     orange       cow    blue
790      apple     sheep  orange
791      apple    monkey  yellow
792     banana       cat  violet
793       kiwi       cat  yellow
794       plum      goat  yellow
795  nectarine       cat   green
796       kiwi       dog  violet
797  nectarine      goat  violet
798     banana       cow     red
799  nectarine    monkey  yellow
```

#### Note:

Alternatively, you could try using **Jupyter notebooks** in VSCode or the less desirable choice of using the **Data Viewer** within Debug mode.

Comment: thing is i did put the option before I printed which is why i am confused. 
Input:
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

df=pd.read_csv("pokemon_data.csv")

print(df)

and it gives me the output i show on top where it cuts off at line 99. I am currently using the data viewer with breakpoint method but it just seems a lil less optimal as it is just gonna show me the whole file.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you. But perhaps the jupyter notebook option would be the best bet then